# Spritekit Game Fails to build on Xcode 6.3 Cannot load module 'SpriteKit' as 'Spritekit'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a SpriteKit Game and it fails with error: 
"**Cannot load module 'SpriteKit' as 'Spritekit'**"

I'm using Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteKit with an uppercase K should do it.

Comment: No thanks is needed if that works for you. You can just accept the answer, that's all the thanks that's needed